# Annotate loops in groovy

Tags: groovy

My groovy script shown below is loaded/compiled at run time. At runtime I am using AST transformations to hook into loops in code. For example I want to do this

```
@SpecialForLoop
for(int i in [1,2,3,4])
{
    Fn1();
    Fn2();
}
```

should be changed to this

```
for (int i in [1,2,3,4])
{
   loopingOnce(); // Custom code I will insert when handling AST
   Fn1();
   Fn2();
   loopOnceDone(); // Custom code I will insert
}
```

I tried setting the annotation as shown, but the compiler complains that this is not a valid location for annotations (ElementType says it can only be on variables, local variables, methods, constructors and method parameters). If I wanted to do this, should I hook into a compiler stage earlier than Semantic Analysis? Is this even possible?

If it is not possible to set the annotation at this place, is there an AST transformation to rename the "for" keyword to "special_for"?

```
special_for(int i in [1,2,3,4,5])
{
   // Do something with i
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this in groovy?

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please provide [mcve], show us what you have tried so far and please reduce your question to the very specific problem that can be easily reproduced by others.

Comment: Ill try to reframe it

Comment: Why don't you just pass a lambda to a function instead?

Comment: No that wont work, because I want the script writer to be unaware and write as if its a for loop.

Comment: Although, thinking further about your suggestion, I can make a Special_For function in the base script class that will take a closure. I can catch all calls to parallelize, ensure they are loops and then substitute the special_for call with just the code block inside the closure. Ill move this suggestion to a reply and lets discuss this there

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion is to do this

```
Special_For({
   for (int i in [1,2,3,4,5])
   {
       // Do something
   }
});
```

Special_For is then a function defined in the base script class that can be detected while parsing the AST. This can then be replaced during AST semantic analysis with the for loop directly.

a) Add an AST transformation
b) In that transformation if the node is a call to method Special_For, then proceed to c)
c) Check if the parameter is a closure, if not throw an error
d) If closure, then get code from closure
e) Make sure that the code from closure is a for loop
f) Replace the methodnode Special_for with code from the closure directly (after adjusting the for loop with your details)

Will this work?

Comment: It could be just a function that accepts Collection/Iterable and Closure. So the call could be like this: forx([1,2,3,5]){ println it } In this case you do not need any AST or annotation...